# Redirect by removing last two letters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I been trying to figure this one out in the htaccess.
I have duplicated posts looking like this:

http://test.se/bank/test-b/
http://test.se/bank/test-b-2/

I would like to redirect the posts ending with -2 to the first url.

Ive got this code so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^-2/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not right as you want to grab everything before `-2` not after it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-2$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I updated my htaccess and the redirect stopped working.. Could anyone see where the problem is?

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+?)-2$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

php_value max_input_vars 3000

</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: This rule should still work but comments are not not good place to solve a problem. I suggest opening a new question with all the details and we'll attend.